# How to make Authentication for another table (not users) in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make another table called students, and i want to connect login with it instead of users table this because "users" name cause problem on my database.

Initially for register i wrote my own code by creating students table and store records on it and it works successfully.

But for the login, i prefer to use laravel login but with students table is there clear steps or something like this?
i want to never use "users" table

Comment: If you're using a `User` model, you can just set `$table = "students"` on the class.

Comment: change table name not working also :(
and i thing it's not duplicate because i want to never use "users" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `auth.php`, `providers` array like this:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        ...
        'model' => App\Student::class,
    ],
    ...
 ]
```

And then update your user model like this:

```
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; //remove this line
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; //Add this line

class User extends Model {
     ...
}
```

Then change your `Students` class to following:

```
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; //Add this
...

class Student extends Authenticatable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: still not working :(
it shows this under email "These credentials do not match our records."

Comment: That error is thrown when the user is not found inside the database..That doesn't mean that something you asked "how to" doesn't work

Comment: yes but the email exist on the database on students table, so I understood from this error that he did not reach the required table "students" and thus i say that the solution did not work

Comment: `"These credentials do not match our records."` means that the `student` in your case wasn't found with the requested `email` AND `password`, not just `email`

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved me !
my error is that i have "Email" column on my table instead of "email"
and "Password" instead of "password", your solution works after i have modified them